# Does Edimax EW-7811Un Support Monitor Mode

Tags: wireless-networking

My question is fairly simple as stated above, does Edimax EW-7811Un Support Monitor Mode. I was reading about network monitoring and wanted to use this with a Raspberry Pi for example to monitor the network. Does this dongle support monitor mode? I could not find any answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Edimax EW-7811Un uses the Realtek RTL8188CUS chipset, which apparently does **not** support monitor mode, at least not under Linux.

Comment: Great, it looks like I need to find another one.

Comment: Have you found a reliable & small usb network adapter that supports monitoring / master mode?

Comment: @Matyas. For monitor mode, you don't want small. You want as many radio chains and as much antenna de-correlation as you can get, so you can capture 2x2 and 3x3 (etc.) transmissions. A tiny 1x1 can't even see most transmissions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. I am currently using it in my kali machine. Monitor mode works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/936545)

Comment: Do you know if this feature was introduced in a specific driver version and/or firmware version? Does your adapter use the same chipset as Spiff mentioned?

Comment: yes, my adapter use the same chipset as spiff mentioned, driver is rtl8192cu. see my terminal output below.
"
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]

Port 3: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtl8192cu, 480M

IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=20 dBm
"
@Burgi i dont care if my answer is accepted or not. this portal has helped me many times, i just wanted to help some

Comment: @Burgi WRONG. This answer is the most perfect answer to the original question. "Does this device support monitor mode?" is everything asked. "Yes" is a perfectly valid answer. What else would you have expected?

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert I respectfully disagree. The answerer has not gone into detail or provided evidence for his statement. Both answers here are borderline for quality. If you check the review link you can see that 4 additional reviewers agreed with me. If you wish to discuss this further please open a [meta] question.